jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/JAXBRIContext"
I'm working on spring parent-2.7.18 to 3.1.10 version migration and I'm using Java 17 version.
I'm getting below error after the migration of Spring-parent 2.x.x to 3.x.x version.
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/JAXBRIContext
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1096)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/JAXBRIContext

here I tried below dependency(Not All at a Time) in pom.xml
      <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
    
      <!-- JAXB RI, Jakarta XML Binding -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>${rpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>


you mean spring boot?

I guess the issue come from scopes remove scopes from dependencies

yes, spring-boot-starter-parent 3.1.10 migrate from 2.7.18

Do not mix javax with jakarta dependencies. Spring Boot 3 uses Jakarta EE 10 and you must update your application completely to use jakarta only.
Run mvn dependency:tree to check if there is no direct or transitive javax dependency being added in your project.
To help you migrate to Jakarta EE 10 check the Open Rewrite recipe. You can run it from Maven command line.

Answering my own question after all observation during migration,  replaced all required javax with Jakarta classes and if any external jar (If latest version not available and we need to continue with older jar) used any javax dependencies then you should also import that dependencies in your pom.xml for compilation purpose because direct reference will not work for compilation.
